# What can you do with the response JSON after uploading media using resumable upload API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

What can you do with the response JSON after uploading media using resumable upload API?

The resumable upload API seems to be working for us just fine...

Request

```
curl -X POST 'https://graph.facebook.com/v19.0/{AppId}/uploads?file_length={FileLength}&file_type=image/jpg&access_token={ActiveToken}'
```

returns

```
[{"id":"upload:{Base64String}?sig={SigString}"}]
```

With that in hand, what's next. The documentation on this ends.
The goal is to upload media to Instagram as a post -- image + caption.

Comment: I don't see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/content-publishing mentioning resumable uploads at all. Do you have any other documentation that indicates those were supported there?

Comment: @CBroe Here you go: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/guides/upload/

Comment: The question was were you actually see it indicated that you _could_ use resumable uploads, when publishing IG media? _"The goal is to upload media to Instagram as a post -- image + caption."_ - the guide to that is under the URL I mentioned. Don't see it saying anything about the possibility to use resumable uploads there.

Comment: @CBroe -- good point.  At that point maybe the question is what they are for?